# Disable autofill in HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, razor

I'm trying to disable autocomplete in two password fields but i couldn't do it. It worked fine with the "autocomplete = off" on textboxes but it didn,t work on password fields.
Thank you in advance.

```
 <div class="form-group" autocomplete="new-password">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-5">

        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @Title = Password, @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "new-password" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" autocomplete="new-password">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "new-password" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Confirmer" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1. Use a  tag for the all html elements as a root. And use **autocomplete="off"** onto that  tag.
2. Then add hidden  with **autocomplete="false"** as a first children element of the form.

If this is not working, feel free to ask for that.

Look for a example :  https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8

Comment: Thank you for your response but i already tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you go through the link I posted..?

Comment: Yes exactly as the link says