# Disable autocomplete/autofill on input in Chrome for Android

Tags: html, forms

**EDIT: this question specifically concerns autofilling on Chrome for Android!**

Here is a screenshot of my progressive web app running on Android (so it's running in Chrome):

[image: The problem]

I've pretty much read every topic on stackoverflow that has "disable" and "autofill" in the title, but I still haven't been able to find a solution.

Over the past year or two, there have been several different versions of Chrome, and in some, one of the following suggestions has worked:

- attribute autofill="off"/"false"/etc... or autocomplete="off"/"false" or autocomplete="" or autocomplete="new-password" on the `<form>` element, as suggested here: [2019, Chrome 76, approach to autocomplete off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367813/2019-chrome-76-approach-to-autocomplete-off/61370224)
- any of these on the `<input>` element
- a hidden input field with one of these attributes before the real one
- any autocomplete="something" that is not on the WHATWG list as suggested here: [Disable autofill in Chrome 63](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775041/disable-autofill-in-chrome-63/47822599)
- attributes role="presentation" and autocomplete="nope" on all input fields as suggested here: [STOP Google Autofill/AutoComplete from ruining my form, Disable autofill on form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415236/stop-google-autofill-autocomplete-from-ruining-my-form-disable-autofill-on-form)
- a combination of autocomplete="off" on the `<form>` element combined with autocomplete="false" on the `<input>` element... as suggested here: [Disable autofill in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526794/disable-autofill-in-html)
- using `input type="search"` (which is actually what I'm trying to achieve), as suggested: [2019, Chrome 76, approach to autocomplete off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367813/2019-chrome-76-approach-to-autocomplete-off)
- javascript solutions like: https://github.com/biesbjerg/jquery.disable-autofill

Nothing seems to work for my `<input type="search">`.
Does anyone have a working solution>.

The problem with Chrome autofilling my search field, is that the suggestions are displayed over my OWN suggestions that are coming from an asychronous call to my database...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that autocomplete="one-time-code" seems to work (for now).
This works on mobile chrome, iOS safari and all common desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the (lookup) bar off on iPhone (see below) but there's no way to turn this off on Droid chrome (as far as I can see).  I've tested everything with a bunch of devices and browsers and you can only turn off the lookup bar on iPhones :-)

To turn off on iPhone (Droid will still show bar but doesn't spell correct):
autocomplete=off autocorrect=off spellcheck={false}

To just turn off auto completions (but leave the suggestions bar on for both phones):
autocomplete=off autocorrect=off